# How to do Naked Objects .NET MVC without persistence

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, naked-objects

I'm looking to re-write an admin app, and I already have a pretty clean domain class library and web services/databases to handle all the business logic and persistence.  That is, the library already provides CreateFoo, GetFoo, and UpdateFoo methods, that by default use existing web services.

I thought I might use [Naked Objects for .NET MVC](http://nakedobjects.net/home/index.shtml) to write a new web admin tool. It seems like Naked Objects assumes that you want the Naked Objects framework to handle both GUI and persistence, but I just want the MVC web site to come from Naked Objects, not the persistence.

Is there any guidance on how to do **GUI-only** Naked Objects for .NET?  **How do I "turn off" the persistence side altogether?**  If I *just try it*, I get an exception "No entity connection strings in App.config file"--of course, I don't want to use any connection strings.

UPDATE: Injecting a new NakedObjects.Persistor.Objectstore.Inmemory.InMemoryObjectPersistorInstaller into the Persistor property in RunWeb.cs seemed to switch me over to in-memory persistence.  Diving a little deeper, it seems as though I might need to implement more complicated interfaces--thus the need for a guide.  Maybe it isn't worth using Naked Objects for applications where we would have to wire up all the persistence logic to fit Naked Objects's interfaces?

Comment: Is *Naked Objects* some framework that I have never heard of, or is it just a notion that you are using to say POCO? Are you talking about view model? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Darin: might be this: http://nakedobjects.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry, added link to clarify for those unfamiliar.

Comment: You might be able to use my project, Noodles to acheive what you are after. It's a NO style framework but doesn't have any tie-in to a particular data architecture: https://github.com/mcintyre321/Noodles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, you can use NO MVC with the in-memory object store.  You need to override

```
protected override IObjectPersistorInstaller Persistor
```

property in the RunWeb class.

But the objects have to come from *somewhere*.  In the case of the in-memory object store, the other installer to look for is the IFixturesInstaller, which defines a set of fixtures (entities) to install into the in-memory objectstore on startup.

Overall, though, it maybe that your use case doesn't particularly fit what NO MVC was designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

looks like [naked objects](http://nakedobjects.codeplex.com/) used EF for persistence. EF is a ORM therefore a db is expected. so the short answer is, you cannot switch from a DB to webservices for persistence because NO is tied to EF.